# How sk_buff points to sk_buff_head

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel

`sk_buff` data structure in linux kernel is organised into a doubly linked list, but the last member and first member of this list are pointing to a `sk_buff_head struct` . However `next` and `prev` members are declared as pointers to `sk_buff` not `sk_buff_head`. How is this possible?

```
struct sk_buff {
  struct sk_buff  * next;
  struct sk_buff  * prev;
  struct sk_buff_head * list;
  struct sock  * sk;
  struct timeval  stamp;
  struct net_device * dev;
  struct net_device * real_dev;
  union private;
  #endif#ifdef CONFIG_NET_SCHED__u32   tc_index;
  #endif
  unsigned int  truesize;
  atomic_t users;
};  



struct sk_buff_head { 
  /* These two members must be first. */ 
  struct sk_buff * next;  
  struct sk_buff * prev;  
  __ U32 qlen;  
  spinlock_t lock;  
};
```

Comment: It is obviously possible.  What about this is confusing to you?

Comment: I mean that `next` and `prev` are declared to point to `sk_buff struct` but the last member of the list has his `next` member pointing to `sk_buff_head struct`. I mean that it is pointing to a different data structure that the declared, so does it use some casting?

Answer (score 2):

every sk_buff structure in that doubly linked list must be able to find the head of whole list quickly. that's the purpose of sk_buff_head structure, which is inserted at the beginning of the list. so, sk_buff_head is a special sk_buff. it wouldn't make any sense to point to another sk_buff_head inside. i think that you would point to the head of whole different doubly linked list, if next and prev members where sk_buff_head...
see the image below for understanding this concept.
[image: sk_buff_head image]

Comment: But `prev` and `next` member of `struct sk_buff` are declared as pointers to `struct sk_buff` not to `struct sk_buff_head`. Its like declaring a pointer to some data type and use it to point to a different data type, its needed some casting operation right?

Comment: next and prev point to sk_buff structs. struct sk_buff has a member called list, which is of type ``struct sk_buff_head*`` and that's the one that points to the head of list (sk_buff_head). the image shows ``list`` member

Comment: But the image shows that for the last member of the list his `next` member is pointing to the `sk_buff_head`, i mean that `list` member and `next` member of the last `sk_buff` of the list are pointing both to the same direction where the head is stored, thought `next` and `list` are declared to point to a different data structure.

Comment: first two members of sk_buff and sk_buff_head are the same, therefore they can be casted one to another (in order to retrieve next or prev member)

Answer (score 1):

As David Miller discribes it in his [website](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html), the sk_buff_head structure is used to place an sk_buff in several lists and make them easy accessible:

```
struct sk_buff {
    /* These two members must be first. */
    struct sk_buff      *next;
    struct sk_buff      *prev;

    struct sk_buff_head *list;
 ...
```

The first two members implement list handling. Packets can exist on several kinds of lists and queues. For example, a TCP socket send queue. The third member says which list the packet is on.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but it works because "next" and "prev" are in the same place (first fields) of both sk_buff and sk_buff_head. The list handling code knows that it might actually be either structure, and casts (coerces) it when necessary to maintain the ring of pointers with one sk_buff_head in the ring.